# Redirect to another page and continue game in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, button

I have made a browser based story RPG game and I would like to redirect the user if they clicked the button.

Here's the HTML for that page unedited:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script defer src="js/game.js"></script>
  <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="topnav">
    <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="text">Text</div>
    <div id="option-buttons" class="btn-grid">
      <button class="btn"></button>
      <button class="btn"></button>
      <button class="btn"></button>
      <button class="btn"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="warning">
      <p>CLICKING NAVIGATION LINKS AT TOP OF PAGE WILL RESET YOUR PROGRESS!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

In the game.js file, I created a function to redirect the user when the button is clicked:

```
function redirect() {
  window.location.href = "/foo/bar.html";
}
```

and here is a snippet of the game to play:

```
{
    id: 2,
    text: 'story',
    options: [{
        text: 'text',
        requiredState: (currentState) => currentState.item,
        setState: {
          item1: false,
          item 2: true
        },
        nextText: 3
      },
      {
        text: 'text',
        requiredState: (currentState) => currentState.item,
        setState: {
          item1: false,
          item2: true
        },
        nextText: 4
      },
      {
        text: 'Attack the enemy!',
        redirect()
      },
```

Notice where redirect() is, that's when it will redirect the player to another part of the site and continue playing or be killed.

The whole div container breaks and does not display anything when I place that redirect() in there.

How do I redirect the user to another html page?

Comment: `here is a snippet of the game to play` looks like an object definition ... do you have an error in the console perhaps? What you may want to look at is documention for event listeners to attach to the buttons so they actually do something

Comment: You can't just drop that `redirect()` in there; that's a syntax error. You need a key, and you need to reference it, not call it: `action: redirect` If you do that, you can do `gameData[123].options[2].action()` to actually call the function.

Comment: Also, what the hell is up with those answers...? And: maybe look into [Inform 7](http://inform7.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [window.open](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) to send to open another webpage, you can also have it to open within itself so that it does so without opening a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Opens in current page

```
function redirect() {
   window.open("bar.html", "_self");
}
```

Same as yours:

```
function redirect() {
  window.location.href = "/foo/bar.html";
}
```

Opens in different tab or what you called (another part of the site)

```
function redirect() {
   window.open("bar.html", "_blank");
}
```